# Aligning Tables Within a Div Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have replaced a table containing four tables (in a grid) with a div-table containing the four tables as cells.  Two things that I absolutely can't seem to get to work are:

1. How do I get rid of the table border of the div tag using `display: table`?
2. The bottom left table insists on lining up with the far left edge of the cell and I want it to line up with the far right edge of the cell.  Even relative positioning is having no impact on this one.

Here is the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .Dashboard {
        display: table;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-width: 0px;
    }
    .row1 {
        display:table-row;
    }
    .row2 {
        display:table-row;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .cell1 {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 2px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .cell2 {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 2px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .cell3 {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 2px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: right;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .cell4 {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 2px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    table.inner {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 2px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2px;
    }
    td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 2px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2px;
    }
    td.image {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

And the table layout looks like this:

```
<div runat="server" id="Dashboard" class="Dashboard">
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="cell1">
            <table class="inner" id="t1">
                <tr>...</tr>
                ...
                <tr>...</tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="cell2">
            <table class="inner" id="t2">
                <tr>...</tr>
                ...
                <tr>...</tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="cell3">
            <table class="inner" id="t3">
                <tr>...</tr>
                ...
                <tr>...</tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="cell4">
            <table class="inner" id="t4">
                <tr>...</tr>
                ...
                <tr>...</tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is the data in this "div table" tabular data or general content?

Comment: The data in the tables is tabular and properly should be in tables.  But they are all different sizes and I want to arrange them neatly on the page.  I was reading that divs were the way to go for this sort of layout but I am having a lot of trouble with it.  I have edited my question to show some code.

Comment: ...why...? If you have tabular data - use tables. If you don't - dont use tables or divs acting like tables! Your markup makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: Can you put this on jsfiddle or something?

Comment: I see no border on your table, only on the cells as you've specified. Also, the lower left cell is right justifying fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rE9Ys/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the border use

```
border: none;
```

With the positioning, find the bottom left table id and use

```
float: right;
```

But your best option is to get rid of tables anyways. All of this can just as easily be done with straight css.